# Non-invocable member 'Vector3' cannot be used like a method. error with wander Ai script

Tags: c#

**I have made a code for my enemy AI in unity to wander around in a top down game. I am very new in C# and for that reason it is very much complicated for me to do the job and understanding everything. Here I did all what I can do and solved most of the errors but I can't find a solution to this error. Please help!!!**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomRoaming : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public Vector3 wayPoint;
    public float Range = 10; 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Wander();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if ((transform.position - wayPoint).magnitude < 3)
        {
            Wander();
        }

    }

    void Wander() {
        wayPoint = Vector3(Random.Range(transform.position.x - Range, transform.position.x + Range), 1, Random.Range(transform.positon.y - Range, transform.position.y + Range));
        wayPoint.z = 0;

        transform.LookAt(wayPoint);
        Debug.log(wayPoint + "and" + (transform.postion - wayPoint).magnitude);
    }

}
```

Comment: `wayPoint = Vector3(Rando...` Use [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) to create an object: `wayPoint = new Vector3(Rando...`

Comment: Fixed that problem but added a new one called "Transform' does not contain a definition for 'positon' and no accessible extension method 'positon' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found"

Comment: It's spelled `position` and not `postion`.

Comment: But I faced another problem, as I hit play it starts to wander around without taking care of the collision and also doesn't remain visible. [I have a navmesh agent on the object and a navmesh on the map]